# Web RTC screen share not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webrtc

I  am using https://simplewebrtc.com/ for webrtc everything is working fine in Firefox but when I  try same in chrome its not working here is my code:-

```
  var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
        localVideoEl: 'local-videos-container',
        remoteVideosEl: 'videos-container',
        autoRequestMedia: false,
        url: '//192.168.1.51:8001'
});

$(document).on('click', '#share-screen', function () {
        webrtc.shareScreen(function (e, d) {
            if (e) {
                alert(e); // throwing NavigatorUserMediaError 
            }
        });
});
```

I  have add chrome extension as well here is code of extension:-

```
{
"name": "Screensharing Sample",
"description": "Screensharing utility sample for getscreenmedia",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"minimum_chrome_version": "34",
"icons": {
 },
 "permissions": [
 "desktopCapture"
 ],
 "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
 "content_scripts": [ {
"js": [ "content.js" ],
 "matches": ["https://192.168.1.51:2013/*"]
 }],
 "externally_connectable": {
   "matches": [        
      "https://192.168.1.51:2013/*"
   ]
  }
}
```

What I  am doing wrong. Please help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are not adding matches domains correctly.try to replace matches with following code:-

replace `"matches": ["https://192.168.1.51:2013/*"]` with `"matches": ["https://192.168.1.51:*/*"]`

let me know if this worked.

Comment: Its working now thanks a lot I waste my 4 hours on this :(

Comment: can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436505/starting-audio-call-only-in-simplewebrtc