# Starting audio call only in SImpleWebRTC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webrtc, html5-audio

I am using  [This](https://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html) jQuery plugin for WebRtc

I want to start audio call only but i can't see any function for this. I am using following code
with autoRequestMedia:false :-

```
 webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
            localVideoEl: 'local-videos-container',
            remoteVideosEl: 'videos-container',
            autoRequestMedia: false,
            url: 'https://192.168.1.11:2001/'
});
```

So when user click on audio call i just want to start audio call only not video 
i can see the method `webrtc.startLocalVideo()` which start audio and video both. so is there any function for audio only?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `media: { audio: true, video: false }` to the constructor of webrtc.

try this:-

```
 webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
        localVideoEl: 'local-videos-container',
        remoteVideosEl: 'videos-container',
        autoRequestMedia: false,
        url: 'https://192.168.1.11:2001/',
        media: { audio: true, video: false }
 );
```